# EF Codefirst and Linq - OrderBy boolean issue

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Im trying to order my data by a boolean value(IsSuggested). But sometimes this query gets 20 result, sometimes 40. I didnt understand whats problem. Then I changed ordering. For example, when I order by "Title" I dont see this problem. Im confused really. What is the problem and what can I do to get recommended deals first?

```
db.Deal
    .Include("Store")
    .Include("Like")
    .Include("Comment")
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.IsRecommend)
    .Skip((syf - 1) * 20)
    .Take(20)
    .ToList()
```

Comment: Did you check the generated SQL?

Comment: yes and query is normal. i see this problem on only boolean ordering.

Comment: I don't see how you can ever get 40 results if you are taking 20. Is this really your exact LINQ statement?

Comment: this is my original query: http://pastebin.com/9p8Xg5aZ

btw i have 350000+ rows in table.

Comment: I changed Include order.

db.Deal.Include("Store").Include("Comment").Include("Like")

Now i dont have any problem :) I guess problem was in generated sql.

Comment: @YakupBuğraBozkurt Could you post this as an answer to your own question and accept it? (Which you can do some hours later). It is OK to do that.

Comment: Can you post the generated SQLs before and after your change?

Answer (score 1):

i needed to order by a boolean value and this was my solution

```
DbContext.Records.Select(t=> new {data = t, isRead = t.Foo == null ? 0 : 1})
.OrderBy(t=> t.isRead)
.Select(t=> t.data).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that using OrderBy with a single boolean property doesn't provide a full ordering of the results. It instead divides the results into two halves with undefined orderying in the two halves. So, for example, if you had an entity with Id, Name, and IsRecommended properties and you just order by IsRecommended, then you might get this ordering:

```
Id  Name  IsRecommended
4   A     true
3   B     true
1   C     true
2   D     false
5   E     false
```

But you might also get

```
Id  Name  IsRecommended
3   B     true
1   C     true
4   A     true
5   E     false
2   D     false
```

Or any other ordering where all the recommended entities come first.

But for Skip and Take to work correctly in LINQ to Entities (and many other LINQ implementations) the ordering of the rows has to be fully determined. This is why the change you indicated in your comment appeared to fix the problem. However, the problem may not be actually fixed if the combination of properties that you are sorting are not guarenteed to be unique.

One way you may be able to ensure you get a fully determined order is to use the primary key as a secondary property to order by. Taking the example above again, this would always result in the following order:

```
Id  Name  IsRecommended
1   C     true
3   B     true
4   A     true
2   D     false
5   E     false
```

and Skip and Take would work consistently.